# Error in using Gdal3.0 static library compiled on win10！

Tags: c++, gdal

I have compiled statical gdal3.0, and got gdal.lib.
[gdal3.0 nmake.opt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO0Dc.png)

when I run my code with stctical lib, error occoured. Error info is “MDd_DynamicDebug” not match “MTd_StaticDebug”.

But,I run my code with Dynamic library, it runs well.

I try to change the Gdal3.0 nmake.opt, but I find no MTd info in the nmake.opt.

Comment: This question belongs as [an issue on their github repository](https://github.com/OSGeo/GDAL/issues). SO is for general questions about programming, while this may point at a bug in that particular project.

Comment: Searching for 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in there does yield some interesting results, such as issues [2308](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2308), [2309](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2309), [this patch](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/c88974a2239b1de0facbf4cc096e0ad75c8e51a6/ports/gdal/0001-Fix-debug-crt-flags.patch) that may solve your problem, and [this comment](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2017-September/047244.html) from the authors.

Comment: thanks, I'll go to their github to ask for help.